# Remove File from file type input before submitting on event with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image

I have a form that allows for the user to select a image form a list or add there own.

When one of the inputs is used I want the other inputs data to be removed. I was able to make the selection option null when selecting a image from the file type input but I don't know how to make the file type null when a optional image is selected.

here is my code example to help people understand:

```js
$('#imglookupbox').on('focus', function(e) {
  $('#imglookupbox + .dropdown .dropdown-menu').show();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('#imglookupbox').length === 0) {
    $('#imglookupbox + .dropdown .dropdown-menu').hide();
  }
});

function Findimage() {
  var Clickedimage = event.target.getAttribute('src');
  var ImageName = FormatURL(Clickedimage);
  var file = $('#image');
  $("#imglookupbox").val(ImageName);
  file[0].files = null;
  $('#imglookupbox + .dropdown .dropdown-menu').hide();
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function previewImage() {
  $("#imglookupbox").val('');
  $("#Imagediscriptextbox").val("N/A");
}

function FormatURL(ImagePath) {
  var Imagename = ImagePath.split('/')[2];
  return Imagename;
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="imglookupbox" name="selctedimage" type="text" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul id="Imageoptions" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <img onclick='Findimage()' class='Img_Selection' src='DataBaseSetup/Images/Image1' alt='image1'>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img onclick='Findimage()' class='Img_Selection' src='DataBaseSetup/Images/Image2' alt='image2'>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img onclick='Findimage()' class='Img_Selection' src='DataBaseSetup/Images/Image3' alt='image3'>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="AddNewImagetxt">
  <p>Add new image.</p>
</div>
<div class="input-group4 Sub" id="UploadImg">
  <input type="file" id="image" name="image" onchange="previewImage()">
</div>
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try this code?
$('[name="image"]').val('');

Comment: Thanks @Ashish that works. I had a feeling it was something simple like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
$('[name="image"]').val('');
```